# Scss works in rails Heroku production but not in staging version

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass, production, staging

I have a rails application on Heroku that works fine [including scss].
However when i try to set up a Heroku staging version by setting up a copy of the environment/production.rb as environment/staging.rb
 and using the following commands:

```
$ heroku create --remote staging
$ heroku config:add RACK_ENV=staging RAILS_ENV=staging --remote staging

$ git push staging master
$ heroku run rake db:migrate --remote staging
$ heroku open --remote staging
```

the staging application on heroku runs but without all the scss/css.

Why does scss work in production but not staging?? 
I thought i understood what the problem was but i now realize I don't.
What do i need to fix?